# Model binding isn't working when htmlAttribute Name is changed on View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I am using ASP.NET MVC to post a strong typed view to a controller this way:

```
@using MyApp.Model
@model UserTest

@{    
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <div>        
        <p>Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Data, new { Name = "txtName" })</p>        
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left; padding-top: 15px">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnSubmit" />
    </div>
}
```

On the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserTest userdata) 
{      
}
```

When I post the form, the `userdata` received has its only property as a `null` value

But, if I remove the `htmlAttribute` that changes the name property of the textbox this way:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <div>        
        <p>Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Data)</p>        
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left; padding-top: 15px">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnSubmit" />
    </div>
}
```

When I post the form, the `userdata` received has a valid property with a value that is correctly bind.

I wonder if I am missing something here because this looks like a bug. If this is the case, should I avoid changing the names of the generated HTML objects on the MVC helpers altogether?.

The version of MVC I have is 5.2.2.0 and the runtime version of the framework is: v4.0.30319

I appreciate the insight on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. This is expected behaviour.

Model binding works by binding the key/value pairs sent by the browser in a form post to model properties (or view data). A form input's `name` attribute is what is used as its key in the form data submitted in a POST request.

When you use HTML helpers to render form fields, the framework automatically generates the appropriate `name` attributes required to ensure that the field will bind properly to the property specified in the expression you pass to the helper.

If you change the `name`, you break the *only* connection between the form input and the property it binds to.

Comment: Hi @AntP, that makes a lot of sense but then I don't understand why they would provide a way to change the name as I did then, Is there a way I can change the actual names display on the HTML source without breaking up the binding mechanism?. Thanks.

Comment: That mechanism is for specifying *any* HTML attribute - it's not specifically for changing the *name* attribute. If you tell the framework you want to override the name attribute, the framework should (and does) defer to your judgment. You might well have a very good reason for doing so (in fact, in more complex binding scenarios the framework is often not quite clever enough to generate the right name itself and you have to give it a helping hand).

Comment: Why do you want to change the names in the HTML source? Posting form values under specified names is a standard HTML convention. If you just want to hide the names of the properties, just use meaningless names (and apologise to your colleagues). If that's not good enough, you'll need to delve deeper and look into custom model binding. I don't really see what this achieves, though.

Comment: I thought that exposing the properties of my model or viewmodel on the HTML source could be somewhat unsafe that's it. Plus l have this habit to put an identifier of the type of the object along with a similar name of the property on HTML objects so that's why.

Comment: You should build your web app under the assumption that anyone can put whatever values they want in your view models on a form post - because they can. As long as you account for that, there's nothing unsafe about exposing the names. The bigger issue is making sure that you don't have any view model properties that can be used maliciously.

Comment: As you say preventing malicious values injection sounds like a much more important thing to care about. Thanks Ant!.

Answer (score 2):

> should I avoid changing the names of the generated HTML objects on the MVC helpers altogether?.

Yes. The input elements' names are what makes model binding work.

So no, not a bug. Don't change them.

You don't explain *why* you want to change them, but you may be able to use a different attribute to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster I want to hide the actual names of the properties from displaying in my HTML, that's why I want the change. How can I use a different attribute to accomplish this without breaking the binding then?.

Comment: @Coder _"I want to hide the actual names of the properties from displaying in my HTML"_ - _why_? The easiest way would be to use a viewmodel with meaningless names though, which you then map to your data model.

Comment: Viewmodels with different property names sound like a good way to do this as you say. I just thought that displaying the same names of my model properties would not be a good practice.